# What criteria should I use to choose between a single-level and multilevel techniques?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am trying to estimate the potential effect of relative consumption (measured as average village level consumption, excluding the household of interest) on reported subjective well-being (measured on a scale ranging from 0 to 10). I use data from two-wave panel study (sample of 1477 households within 18 villages).

First, I have estimated Pooled OLS, Pooled ordered probit, and Correlated Random effects probit model, with standard errors clustered at the individual level (households). All the models control for own household consumption expenditure among other variables. I found a positive coefficient estimate on both own consumption and relative consumption variables. However, the coefficient on relative consumption becomes negative when I use three-level linear model, which corrects for both individual and village random effects.

What criteria should I use to choose between a single-level and multilevel techniques?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Nice question. Assuming you're familiar with the literature on HLMs including Gelman and Hill *Data Analysis Using Regression...*, Singer's *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* or Raudenbush's *Hierarchical Linear Modeling*, you're aware that there are no easy answers or prescriptions. For instance, on page 46 of Singer's book sec 3.1 is titled, "What is the purpose of the multilevel model for change?" where she writes, "Statistical models are not statements about sample behavior; they are statements about the *population process* that generated the data." Which model does this?